# want an explaination for attributes usage of spark sql example code in official document

Tags: apache-spark-sql

In [spark 2.0.1 sql document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#interoperating-with-rdds), 
I have three questions about following code snippets

1) what's attributes? where can I find the document?

2) `=>` means what?

3) I search [the APIs for RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/api/core/spark/RDD.html), but do not find toDF function. Why can call `.toDF` here?

```
// Create an RDD of Person objects from a text file, convert it to a Dataframe.
     val peopleDF = spark.sparkContext.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")
    .map(_.split(","))
    .map(attributes => Person(attributes(0), attributes(1).trim.toInt))
    .toDF()
```

Comment: The arrow symbol separates arguments from the return expression.
I google this and find the answer for 1st and 2nd question.
so, attributes is a parameter, and => is a lambda keyword.